# Convert XML to PDF using XSLT without xls-fo

Tags: pdf, xslt

I need to convert the XML to PDF using XSLT only without third party dll. Please find the following XML.

```
<xml>
  <Roll No> 60246</Roll No>
  <Document No> 60246</Document No>
  <Name>Satheesh</Name>
  <Class>III</Class>
  <Section>B</Section>
  <Contact No>9876543210</Contact No>
 <Exams>
    <Exam> Quaterly </Exam>
    <Tamil> 75 </Tamil>
    <English> 80 </English>
    <Maths> 80 </Maths>
    <Total> 480 </Total>
 </Exams>
 <Exams>
   <Exam> Half yearly </Exam>
   <Tamil> 100</Tamil>
   <English> 100 </English>
   <Maths> 100 </Maths>
  <Total>480 </Total>
 </Exams>
</xml>
```

[I need the below out format using XSLT only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8X8X.png)

Comment: XSLT can generate HTML, XML and text, whereas PDFs are binary files. Typically you would create XSL-FO from your XML and use a tool like Apache FOP to create the PDF. If you are really asking "How do a I create a PDF from XSL-FO without using a third party tool?" then the answer to this is "Use a third party tool" as if you hunt down the PDF specification, you will see it it is rather complicated....

Comment: @TimC Technically, a PDF with unencoded streams (and no images, etc.) _is_ a text file ... but I agree that writing even a simple helloworld.pdf without some kind of library/tool would be a daunting task.

Comment: Er, in addition to what @TimC said, it should probably be pointed out that your input is not in fact XML.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to create a PDF for simple Hello World without XSL-FO.