# Generate a dynamic PDF from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert my XML to pdf file. So please find the sample XML file.

```
<xml>
    <Roll No> 60246</Roll No>
    <Document No> 60246</Document No>
    <Name>Satheesh</Name>
    <Class>III</Class>
    <Section>B</Section>
    <Contact No>9876543210</Contact No>
    <Exams>
        <Exam> Quaterly </Exam>
        <Tamil> 75 </Tamil>
        <English> 80 </English>
        <Maths> 80 </Maths>
        <Total> 480 </Total>
    </Exams>
    <Exams>
        <Exam> Half yearly </Exam>
        <Tamil> 100</Tamil>
        <English> 100 </English>
        <Maths> 100 </Maths>
        <Total>480 </Total>
    </Exams>
</xml>
```

I need to convert the above xml file to below-attached pdf format. So can any suggest an idea?

Sample pdf screenshot:

[image: Click to sample pdf]

Comment: This seems an exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365488/convert-xml-to-pdf-using-xslt-with-out-xls-fo). If you need to convert XML file to PDF, please check whether you can use `itext` jars. The PDF template needs to be created and using XPath you can access the data from the XML

Comment: Have a look a XSL-FO.